# What is the field that studies community responses to incentives?

Tags: terminology, reference-request, social-psychology

Having recently read [Freakonomics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freakonomics) I was particularly interested by the idea of the responses of a community to incentives - as an example, the tale of a school which tried to introduce a financial penalty for picking up children late, which inadvertently had the opposite effect, as it nullified the previously existing (but largely invisible) social penalty.

Is there a general theory for this kind of interaction of incentives with community? If so, what is its name, and where could I read more about it? I'm interested in books and papers on a variety of levels, from popular accounts (à la Freakonomics) to textbooks to research papers.

Comment: This is pretty much all economics.  Just depends on the scope of your community (localized, national, firms, individuals, etc.), and the incentives (prices, taxes, interest rates, punishments, etc.).  I suspect what you're looking for would be contained in the broadly-defined category of applied microeconomics, but unless you can better articulate what exactly it is that you want, I'm not sure how much help anyone can be.

Comment: @prototoast, yes.  And you could throw in parts of sociology and political science as well.

Comment: If you haven't run across them already, I'd recommend books by **Malcolm Gladwell**, particularly *The Tipping Point*.  It has a competing explanation for the crime drop (less graffiti), though personally I found the Steve's argument more convincing (more abortions).

Answer (score 4):

There is a specific field of economics that deals with the process of changing people's responses through incentives: [Behavioural Economics.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_economics)

> study the effects of social, cognitive and emotional factors on the
>   economic decisions of individuals and institutions and the
>   consequences for market prices, returns and the resource allocation.

[A recent issue of The Economist](http://www.economist.com/node/21551032) covers some of the current approaches used by governments to change individual behaviour:

> Behavioural economists have found that all sorts of psychological or
>   neurological biases cause people to make choices that seem contrary to
>   their best interests. The idea of nudging is based on research that
>   shows it is possible to steer people towards better decisions by
>   presenting choices in different ways.

Some of the approaches, for instance used by the British Behavioural Insights Team, are merely ways of changing a message:

> The Nudge Unit has been running dozens of experiments and the early
>   results have been promising*. In one trial, a letter sent to
>   non-payers of vehicle taxes was changed to use plainer English, along
>   the line of “pay your tax or lose your car”. In some cases the letter
>   was further personalised by including a photo of the car in question.
>   The rewritten letter alone doubled the number of people paying the
>   tax; the rewrite with the photo tripled it.

It's become a very fruitful area of research so would recommend taking your interest further.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect economics is not the best framework for this because financial incentives are actually very limited in their efficacy in real-world contexts. The example in the question is a good demonstration: the financial incentive was a lot weaker than the social incentive it replaced. [Applied Psychology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applied_psychology) might be a better place to look, in part because it requires a more or less explicit theory of decision-making and behavior change.

Comment: Economics does not imply financial incentives only.

Answer (score 2):

[**Game Theory**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_theory) has principles to contribute, such as the [Nash Equilibrium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_equilibrium).

> A set of strategies is a Nash equilibrium if each represents a best response to the other strategies. So, if all the players are playing the strategies in a Nash equilibrium, they have no unilateral incentive to deviate, since their strategy is the best they can do given what others are doing.

Change the incentives in a community, and it can be expected to migrate from one Nash Equilibrium to another.  This would attempt to account for the knock-on or ripple effects, e.g. late pick-up fee makes parents less respectful of the teachers who have to stay late, and resentful teachers make students more cynical, etc.